# React With Same String Comparison Using === Always Evaluates False

Tags: javascript, reactjs, compare, string-comparison

I have a component which  uses some state passed down from a parent. The component will render if the user is logged in and a string matches. If so display otherwise dont. I've printed `=` in to console to ensured the strings had no spaces.

Though the conditional statement is correct "NOT OWNER" still shows when it should be "OWNER".

Here is the component simplified:

```
import React from "react";

const EditButton= ({
  isUserLoggedIn,
  username,
  sellersUsername,
}) => {
  return (
    <>
      {isUserLoggedIn&& username === sellersUsername? (
        <>OWNER</>
      ) : (
        <>NOT OWNER</>
      )}

      {console.log(`=${isUserLoggedIn}=`)}
      {console.log(`=${username}=`)}
      {console.log(`=${sellersUsername}=`)}
      {console.log(username=== sellersUsername)}
      {console.log(
        username.localeCompare(sellersUsername, "en", {
          sensitivity: "base",
        })
      )}
      {console.log(isUserLoggedIn&&username===sellersUsername)}
    </>
  );
};

export default GalleryEditButton;
```

The output:

```
// should evaluate to true but does not
=true=
=RandomTestUsername=
=RandomTestUsername=
false
0
false
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What if you remove the `isUserLoggedIn &&` part, and do `{console.log( username === sellersUsername )}`? Also try `username.localeCompare( sellersUsername , 'en', { sensitivity: 'base' }  )`

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the additional test cases. I've updated the post based on your suggestion with the results. It looks like no differences between the usernames but they evaluate to false still. Any other suggestions I can check?

Comment: Your `localeCompare` returns `0` when the strings are considered equal.

Comment: _"Any other suggestions"_ - ...you **have** used your step-through debugger by now, right?

Comment: Yes I have. I am using the chrome extension DevTools to monitor state and props of react components. I also used VSCode to attach a debugger and step into the code. I feel like it  is something simple I overlooked

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the `{console.log(username=== sellersUsername)}` line and then share a screenshot of your Watch/Scope pane that shows `username` and `sellersUsername`.

Comment: I gave it another look and resolved the issue. Someone mentioned it may not be strings. I realized one was an `object` which helped narrow down my issue. Thanks for the help again!

Comment: After such frustration Im migrating the project to Typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to check the typeOf the two variables. Because === is a strict checking that is case sensitive and also types sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I think this was part of the issue. I was using a 3rd party library which returns `username` as an object and while `sellerUsername` was String. But now they are both strings it looks like it could be spme state issue.

Comment: Thanks. This was it. After giving it another look, I had to convert the object to string then lowertcase. The libraries I used differed in usernames sometimes. `String(username).toLocaleLowerCase();` Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

[Code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pak22.png)

I tried running a similar scenario on my machine and the results were the ones you'd expect.

My suggestion is try tracking the state update of "username" and "sellersUsername," maybe one of them is not being updated.

The problem is most likely at one of these 2 props since  `username === sellersUsername` is what's returning false.

Comment: You are right it could be state. I've monitored it closely and the state appears to propagate correctly. Thanks for your suggestion